# VSCode settings : colorize custom tags that start with the "x-" prefix

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to write a vscode setting in which tags ( inside .vue file ) that start with the prefix `x-` will be colored green.

tags like `<x-component></x-component>` and `<x-lorem></x-lorem>`

is it possible? and how

i tried this

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": "entity.name.tag.x-*",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#00ff00"
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

and it not works

Comment: use the extension: **Highlight**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that this is not possible without installing the plugin
I used the [`Highlight`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight) plugin mentioned by [@rioV8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9938317/riov8)
it works

this is my config :

```json
  "highlight.regexes": {
    "(<[^>]*x-[^>]*>)": { // A regex will be created from this string, don't forget to double escape it
      "decorations": [ // Decoration options to apply to the capturing groups
        { "color": "#7ac379" }, // Decoration options to apply to the first capturing group, in this case "//<-x:"
      ]
    }
  }
```